# Python exec not picking up scope when called via a function

Tags: python, scope, python-exec

I have a function `test()` that should check if a string is a valid Python file. (The string is typically extracted from a readme or so.) Running `exec()` on the string works well, unless in this situation:

```py
string = """
import math

def f(x):
    return math.sqrt(x)

f(2.0)
"""

# no problem:
# exec(string)


def test():
    exec(string)

test()  # NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d.py", line 17, in <module>
    test()
  File "d.py", line 15, in test
    exec(string)
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in f
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

Why does `exec()` not pick up on the `import math` if called through a function, but works when running it in the main scope? How to work around it within `test()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to explain properly but it will work if you do this:

```
def test():
    exec(string, {"__MODULE__": "__main__"})
```

Basically, the `import math` does not exist in the `f` function unless it's declared in the main scope.